# Are there css selectors that apply regardless of the contents of the html file?

Tags: html, css

I am looking through the contents of the http://www.initializr.com responsive template and I am trying to work out what I need to keep from the main.css file.

There are lots of selectors in here for classes that will not be turning up in my html file. For instance

```
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {style}

.ir {style}
```

Or again for elements that I do not intend to use:

```
thead, 
tr {style}

fieldset, 
textarea {style}
```

If I am not using any such elements/classes should I even keep these? Lots of them are listed under 'helper classes' or 'initial styles' so I was wondering if there are any selectors that browsers apply regardless of the contents of the html file.

This may be a simple question - my main concern is cross browser compatibility, especially since I don't have regular access to a windows machine (hence why I have gone with the template) - basically I don't want to wipe something out that was supposed to smooth out IE issues.

Comment: In general, it's not going to hurt to keep those css rules in there... If the HTML elements do not exist then they won't apply to anything and you don't risk the chance of removing something that may have been necessary. It's not like you're going to have any (noticeable) performance hit or anything with a few more lines of CSS...

Comment: Thanks, I'm just a bit adverse to having code that I don't fully understand hanging around, especially if it isn't doing any good.

Comment: I agree with Dryden. You may not have any table elements now (or ever), but if you did add them later, they might look strange without those styles.

Comment: Another general rule is that if you don't fully understand it, leave it alone. Most of these templates are made by pros, so they have the rules in there for a reason. Better to leave it as-is than try to manipulate something you don't fully know how to fix. CSS will not dynamically create anything, so leaving extra CSS in the file that has no elements to target will have zero effect on your site.

Comment: Good point I guess, but if they only apply to my html then there is little risk of me accidentally putting a .visuallyhidden.focusable class, for instance - either way, thanks for your quick responses, at least it works as I'd assume (i.e. only to classes in the html file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rule of thumb with templates and frameworks is to leave them alone if you don't understand them and don't want to learn them. Beside putting some overhead on your clients (downloading more than they need) nothing bad will happen from these styles.

It's easy to dissect them if you understand them or important if you want to learn the stuff behind them.

But in your case, use it and go on.

Comment: I do want to learn the stuff behind them, hence why I am investigating the contents rather than just going ahead with the template as is, or using a generic bootstrap template. My only question was if there were css selectors that would apply regardless of the html file. As there are not I'm emptying out the css file to keep it as minimal as possible, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Only the selectors that match anything within your particular file are applied and removing everything else is good because your clients will have less content to download.